# How do I output multiple linear regression slopes to new list?

Tags: r, regression

I have a data.frame and a list of observation 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1CTY.jpg

and a list of observation times
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV5LR.jpg

and I want to create a list with the linear regression line slopes from each column of that data frame and the observation times.

If i was doing it all manually, I'd do:

> raw_slope <- lm(score1$AKR ~ obs)
>
> slope <- raw_slope$coefficients[[2]]

and then "slope" is the value I want. I'm trying to understand how i can run something and spit out the slope for each of the 19 company symbols in my data.frame.

I'm kind of a novice at R but I'm trying to learn it, I appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.

EDIT2: I ran lm(score1$... ~ obs) for each of the rows manually so i know the calculations should all work out.

EDIT: I tried the suggestion from the comments

> listslope<-lapply(score1, function(x) coef(lm(x~obs))[2])

and am getting

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
>     0 (non-NA) cases

I'm going to try and figure out what's causing the issue, but I wanted to update my post and say thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lapply(score1, function(x) coef(lm(x~obs))[2])
```

Should give it to you in a list.

Use `sapply` if you'd prefer a vector.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looked like there was an extra ")" to in your script, so i adjusted it and still got an error. I'm looking it up now to see what might be going wrong, thanks for showing me function and lapply.




Here's there error:
http://imgur.com/NLfcXUG